# Cart quote returns null

Tags: magento2

```
 protected $cart;

 \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,

 $this->cart = $cart;
```

Why returns null ?

```
$this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
```

and

```
$this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
```

And with session same result.

Comment: where you have call it?

Comment: Do you mean in frontend or backend or in which files ?

Comment: on which files you inject the class `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,`

Comment: vendor/module/Block/Adminhtml/CartInfo/Index.php

Comment: $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection(); returns all cart info but i need only visible items

Answer (score 1):

You can not use **the frontend Cart class for backend** and `vendor/module/Block/Adminhtml/CartInfo/Index.php` is a backend class.

If you need to use `\Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote` for getting current admin quote and it will work at the admin order create page.

Comment: Can You  send as  get from this  carts information ? thanks very much

Comment: Can you please describe your requirement?

Comment: I created a page in the admin panel and there I need to show all the products that are currently in the basket